# Upvotes are not shown in close vote review queue for a question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues

This is the link to the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/25821630).

**Logged out**                                                             **Logged in**
[image: comparison]

Comment: That's likely means it is audit... You payed attention... passed.